Compatibility issue with dacastro4/laravel-gmail after upgrading Laravel to version 10 and PHP to 8.2
I recently upgraded my Laravel application from version 5 to 10 and PHP from 7 to 8.2. After the upgrade, I'm encountering an issue with the dacastro4/laravel-gmail package:
  Problem 1
    - dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v0.1, ..., v0.6.2, v1.0.0, ..., v1.2, v2.0, ..., v2.0.4, v3.0.0] require illuminate/auth ~5.0|~5.1|~5.2|~5.3 -> found illuminate/auth[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v3.1.0, ..., v3.2.6, v4.0, ..., v4.0.41, v5.0.0, ..., v5.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v5.1.1, ..., v5.1.21] require illuminate/auth ~5.8|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v6.0, ..., v6.1] require illuminate/auth ~5.8|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires dacastro4/laravel-gmail * -> satisfiable by dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v0.1, ..., v0.6.2, v1.0.0, ..., v1.2, v2.0, ..., v2.0.4, v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.6, v4.0, ..., v4.0.41, v5.0.0, ..., v5.1.21, v6.0, v6.1].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require dacastro4/laravel-gmail:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require dacastro4/laravel-gmail:^2.1" if you know which you need.


It seems that the package requires illuminate/auth versions that are not compatible with Laravel 10. Is there a way to resolve this issue or are there alternative packages for Gmail integration in Laravel 10 and PHP 8.2?
Here's my composer.json dependencies related to this package:
    "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.313",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.8",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.16",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "intervention/image": "2.7.2",
    "jenssegers/agent": "*",
    "laracasts/flash": "*",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/horizon": "*",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.28",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "*",
    "mailerlite/mailerlite-api-v2-php-sdk": "^0.3.2",
    "morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear": "^1.2",
    "nayjest/grids": "^2.0",
    "niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf": "*",
    "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2",
    "predis/predis": "*",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "*",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.13",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^7.1",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "^7.1"
  },

Any help or guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

dacastro4/laravel-gmail is up to v6.1 but it only lists up to 3.0. Do you have a version constraint in your composer.json? Can you show the rest of your composer.json?


dacastro4/laravel-gmail[v6.0, ..., v6.1] require illuminate/auth ~5.8|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

I try command 'composer require dacastro4/laravel-gmail' and get this error

Please [edit] your post and add in your full composer.json. It sounds like there may be a conflict with another library.

morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear is meant for Laravel 5. Same for nayjest/grids, so those might cause conflicts. When doing a big version jump, I'd recommend removing all of the extra packages and install/require them one-by-one to make sure the versions are compatible.  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/composer.json is the base composer.json that you can start with

I deleted old composer.json, composer.lock, vendor. Take laravel 10 composer.json and install all packages one by one. I have conflicts only for laravel-gmail with illuminate/auth version

Can you [edit] your post with the full output when you try to install it?

Odd. It's saying that laravel-gmail 6.1 requires as high as illuminate/auth 9.0, but the composer.json on GitHub shows 10 as well. Try composer clear-cache and try again.

It could also be that packagist is not updated (https://packagist.org/packages/dacastro4/laravel-gmail still shows 9). You might need to raise an issue on their github
